# Hyperlink.Address property returns partial URL after hash character

Tags: excel, vba

If a cell hyperlink points to a URL that contains `#`, the [`Address` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hyperlink.address) of the `Hyperlink` object only returns everything up to that character.

For instance, create a cell with any content and add a hyperlink to, e.g. `http://www.google.com/#Test`. Then, run the following macro after selecting that cell:

```vb
Sub ShowURL()
    MsgBox (Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Address)
End Sub
```

Here is all you get:

[image]

Does Excel process characters after `#` differently (e.g. if they are assumed to be anchors)?

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it: everything after `#` is returned by the [`SubAddress` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hyperlink.subaddress).